# how to empty ul autocomplete JqueryMobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, html-lists

I have a website that uses an ul element to do autocomplete (using JQueryMobile).
First time that I load the page, I can enter some text to ul input (ul with data-role listview) and it's save in the db.
Then, I redirect into other site, but when I turn again to the same web, the data that I entered in ul input are still there! And it show me an error when I send it to db (error because I need to empty fields before I send).

How can I empty the ul fields when I recharge the web? I tried with

```
$("ul").html(" "); //not work
$("#id_div").remove(); //destroy the web and I can't enter again
$("#id_div").empty(); //same as above
```

Thanks and sorry for my bad english!

EDIT:

I have differents functions:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#confirm", function() {

    if(typeof localStorage.emails === 'undefined' || localStorage.emails === null){
        var mail = [];
        localStorage.emails = JSON.stringify(mail);
    }


    $( "#confirm_email1" ).on( "listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
        var $ul = $( this ),
        $input = $( data.input ),
        value = $input.val(),
        html = "";
        $ul.html( "" );
        if ( value && value.length > 1 ) {

            var emails = JSON.parse(localStorage.emails)
            for(var i=0;i < emails.length;i++){
                html += "<li>" + emails[i] + "</li>";
            }
            $ul.html( html );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
            $('li').click(function(){
                var mail = $(this).text();
                $input.val(mail);
                $ul.html( "" );
                $ul.listview( "refresh" );
                save_email1="";
                enviar_email1=mail;
            });

            save_email1 = $input.val();
            enviar_email1 = save_email1;
        }
    });
```

Using this function I create localStorage to add dinamically the li elements to autocomplete.

Then, I use this other one:

```
function enviarReserva(){

    if(save_email1!==""){
        var emails = JSON.parse(localStorage.emails);
        emails.push(save_email1);
        localStorage.emails=JSON.stringify(emails);
    }

    var horafi = parseInt(horaReserva)+1;

    var check_soci1;

    if((enviar_email1!='' ) && (document.getElementById("soci_nosoci1").checked!=true)){
        check_soci1="no";
    }else{
        check_soci1="yeh";
    }

    $.ajax ( {
        beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); }, //Show spinner
        complete: function() { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg() }, //Hide spinner
        url: "someURL?email1="+enviar_email1+"&check1="+check_soci1,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(data);
            actualitzarReserves();
            $.mobile.changePage("#mon",{transition:'none'});
            pag = 0;
            $('.pagina').html(pag);
            chargeWallet();
        },
        error: function (data, textStatus, jqHXR) {
            window.location.href="index.html";
        }
    });
}
```

This function check if the ul is empty or not and if the check is selected. Then, the PHP return something if check_soci is no or something else if check_soci is yeh.

My problem is that the second time that I enter the same web, the ul is not empty by default and although I empty the input it sends to PHP that the check_soci is no. ERROR!!

Comment: It is expected that `$("#id_div").remove();` does the same as `$("#id_div").remove();`

Comment: could you please put the code on fiddle.

Comment: Did you put your code in a `$(document).ready(function(){/* here */});` ?

Comment: You have to reset the form fields values to `''` on `pageshow` instead of removing them. Bind this handler on inside your `pageinit` handler so it will only fire on second appearance of the page.

Comment: A little like: http://jsfiddle.net/ntMb3/